# How do I get the browser to wait with Capybara & Kimurai?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, capybara, kimurai

I'm scraping [this page][1] to look for details of schools that are contained within the CSS selectors `.box .column` which is contained within a div `.schools` which is loaded dynamically and takes some time to appear.

I've done this with the **watir** gem and had no problems. Here's the code as reference.

```rb
    browser = Watir::Browser.new
    browser.goto('https://educationdestinationmalaysia.com/schools/pre-university')
    js_doc = browser.element(css: '.schools').wait_until(&:present?)
    schools_list = Nokogiri::HTML(js_doc.inner_html)
    school_cards = schools_list.css('.box .columns .column:nth-child(2)')
```

I'm now trying to achieve the same with the `kimurai` gem but I'm not really familiar with Capybara.

### What I've Tried

- Changing the default max wait time

```rb
  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
       Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 20
       puts browser.has_css?('div.schools')
   end
```

- `using_wait_time`

```rb
  browser.using_wait_time(20) do
     puts browser.has_css?('.schools')
   end
```

- Passing in a `wait` argument to `has_css?`

```rb
   browser.has_css?('.schools', wait: 20)
```

Thanks for reading!
[1]: https://educationdestinationmalaysia.com/schools/pre-university

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Watir code

```
js_doc = browser.element(css: '.schools').wait_until(&:present?)
```

returns the element, but in your Capybara code you're calling predicate methods (has_css?, has_xpath?, has_selector?, etc) that just return true or false. Those predicate methods will only wait if `Capybara.predicates_wait` is true. Is there a specific reason you're using the predicates though? Instead you can just `find` the element you're interested in, which will wait up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` or you can specify a custom wait option.  The "equivalent" to your Watir example of

```
js_doc = browser.element(css: '.schools').wait_until(&:present?)
schools_list = Nokogiri::HTML(js_doc.inner_html)
school_cards = schools_list.css('.box .columns .column:nth-child(2)'
```

assuming you had Capybara.default_max_wait_time set to a number high enough for your app and testing setup

```
school_cards = browser.find('.schools').all('.box .columns .column:nth-child(2)')
```

If you do need to extend the wait for one of the finds you could do

```
school_cards = browser.find('.schools', wait: 10).all('.box .columns .column:nth-child(2)')
```

to wait up to 10 seconds for the `.schools` element to appear. This could also just be collapsed into

```
school_cards = browser.all('.schools .box .columns .column:nth-child(2)')
```

which will also wait (up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time) for at least one matching element to exist before returning it although depending on your exact HTML

```
school_cards = browser.all('.schools .column:nth-child(2)')
```

may be just as good and less fragile

Note: you do have to be using a Kimurai engine that supports JS -  https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework#available-engines - otherwise you won't be able to interact with dynamic websites

Comment: Thanks Thomas! My reasoning for using a selector was to check if the element existed. Unfortunately I seem to be getting an error using the **find** & **all** method, ``Invalid expression: .schools``. And yes I've installed selenium chrome, selenium firefox & phantomJS as recommended on Kimura's documentation.

Comment: @SamLee it’s possible your configuration is defaulting to XPath, please try `find(:css, ‘.schools’)` instead

Comment: Thanks Thomas! It worked! Another error I made was not declaring the engine in my model to be selenium_chrome, so Kimurai defaulted to mechanize.